# sqlite extra column with 1 and 0 if record exists in related table or not

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am not so good at SQL, so I have the following tables

**Stuff**

[image: Workers]

and

**Specialty**

[image: specialties]

Let's say, the worker with name 'Bob' has two specialties. How could I get the specialty table with an extra column (let's say count) which has 1 if the record exists in Stuff and 0 otherwise.

I would like to ask if there is any way to cast a query
that returns a result for Bob as shown below?

[image]

Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.
(I am not sure about the title. Please do suggest if you have a better idea!)

Comment: then why `mathematics` is `0` in result

Comment: because I am getting results for Bob. Not for Dan. The third Table is results for Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to do this with a `case` and `exists`:

```
select sp.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from stuff s
                          where s.surname = 'Bob' and
                                s.speciality_code = sp.speciality_code
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as BobHas
from specialty sp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Left Outer join` with `Null` check. Try this.

```
SELECT sp.specialitycode,
       sp.description,
       CASE
         WHEN st.specialitycode IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END AS count
FROM   speciality sp
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT specialitycode
                        FROM   stuff
                        WHERE  surname = 'Bob') st
                    ON sp.specialitycode = st.specialitycode
```

Comment: hello my friend! I get this error: no such column: st.specialty_code. Why?

Comment: @VassilisDe - it should be `st.specialtycode` instead of `st.specialty_code`. updated check now