# sqlite show 1 and 0 if record exists or not doesn't work

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I would like to take a step further my former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989232/sqlite-extra-column-with-1-and-0-if-record-exists-in-related-table-or-not)
So, supposing we have some students who attend some courses at specific time periods, we get those tables

[image: student]

[image: attends]

[image: course]

where fields in bold are the primary keys

In Attends table, attendsId PK,
(stRegNum, courseCode,periodId) FK

For **Student with id = 00001** I want to show all courses who attends with a 1 before of them and a 0 for those who doesn't. Like this

[image]

I created a query to see how it works

```
select (
  case when exists(
    select 1
    from course 
    where attends.stRegNum = '00001' 
    group by course.courseCode
  )
  then 1
  else 0
  end
) as hh, *
from course left join attends on course.courseCode = attends.courseCode
```

and I get this

[image: whatIget]

which is obviously wrong. I know that left join messes it up, but everything I tried, I couldn't get the expected results.

Could someone please tell me where I'm doint wrong, and how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

***PS:*** I am not sure about the title. Please do suggest if you have a better idea!

Comment: What is the GROUP BY meant to do?

Comment: as you see, even for student with regNum=00001, I get the same course 2 times. That's because he attends it for 2 time periods. So, I thought it would be a good idea to group by courses in order to have -Math for example- only one time. But nothing happened...

Comment: The EXISTS will be TRUE as long as the sub-query returns one or more rows, no matter how many. I.e. the GROUP BY doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Student '00001', you can see which courses they've attended by first selecting all the courses and then joining to the attends table, flagging with a 1 all the courses that that 00001 attended:

```
select distinct
        course.courseCode
        ,case when attends.attendsId is not null then 1 else 0 end as attendedCourse

from course 
        left join attends
        on course.courseCode = attends.courseCode
        and attends.stRegNum = '00001'
```